# Set default size of the artboard of imported Photoshop work paths

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am using Illustrator 2018 on Windows.

I am working with a series of Photoshop work paths (exported from Photoshop 2018) which are all made using a 300 dpi bmp.

Until recently when I opened a work path file in Illustrator it placed the imported paths on a square artboard which was always the same size each time I opened a path.

I do not know what or how but something has changed and each path is now placed on a thin rectangle shaped artboard. This is annoying as I now have to manually resize each artboard.

Is there a way to set the default artboard so that each time an image or path is opened or imported the artboard is the same size?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just following your last used artboard setting.

To reset it:

Create a new document **File → New** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)

And choose the desired artboard size and hit <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Next time you load something in, it will create the artboard based off your last used size.